# How to allocate memory for specific number of strings?

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, allocation

I was given the task to program something like a dictionary, and the way I am allocating memory for the meanings is just to allocate for 100 meanings in the constructor, which works perfectly fine.

However, the professor didn't approve that and he asked me to rewrite the code in a way that I allocate memory for a relevant number of meanings. I basically have no idea how to do that, how the constructor will know in advance how many meanings I will have?

What would you guys suggest? I post just part of the code, which is relevant for the problem.

```
#include"expression.h"

//---------------------METHODS-------------------------------------------

Expression::Expression(int m_ctr)
{
    count_meanings = m_ctr; // Set the counter to 0
    meanings = new char * [100]; // Allocate memory for 100 meanings
}

Expression::~Expression()
{
    delete [] meanings; // Free the allocated memory
    delete [] word_with_several_meanings; // Free the allocated memory
}

void Expression::word(char *p2c)
{
    word_with_several_meanings = new char[strlen(p2c)+1];
    strcpy(word_with_several_meanings, p2c); // copy the string, method: DEEP copy
}

void Expression::add_meaning(char *p2c)
{
    meanings[count_meanings] = new char[strlen(p2c)+1];
    strcpy(meanings[count_meanings++], p2c); // copy the string, method: DEEP copy
}

char * Expression::get_word()
{
    return word_with_several_meanings;
}

char * Expression::get_meaning(int n_meaning)
{
    return * (meanings + n_meaning);
}

int Expression::get_total_number_of_meanings()
{
    return count_meanings;
}

int main(void)
{
    Expression expr;

    expr.word("bank");
    expr.add_meaning("a place to get money from");
    expr.add_meaning("a place to sit");

    cout << expr.get_word() << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<expr.get_total_number_of_meanings(); i++)
        cout << " " << expr.get_meaning(i) << endl;
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings if this is meant to be a C++ assignment ?

Comment: well, this one is actually a p2p variable **meanings

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah See "add_meaning" for where those allocations are

Answer (score 3):

The **C++** way of doing that is to use:

- `std::string` to store a single string (instead of raw char* C-like strings)
- `std::vector` to store a sequence of strings (like the "meanings" in your dictionary)

So, you can have a `vector<string>` data member inside your class, and you can dynamically add meanings (i.e. `string`s) to it, using `vector::push_back()`.

If you - for some reason - want to stay at the raw C level, you could use a [*linked list*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) data structure, storing a raw C string pointer inside each node, and when you add a new meaning, you can create a new node pointing to that string, and add that node to the linked list. A singly-linked list having a node definition like this may suffice:

```
struct MeaningListNode 
{
    char * Meaning;                 // Meaning raw C string
    struct MeaningListNode* Next;   // Pointer to next meaning node, or nullptr for last
};
```

But, frankly speaking, the `vector<string>>` approach seems much simpler and better to me.

Comment: Discarded an answer along these lines and deleted it. I'd just like to quote from it: "All this C-ish fiddling with char arrays - arrgh!" So, don't stay at the "raw C level", there's no excuse for it.